# How to print json ouput on console

Tags: iphone, json, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook graph API and getting its result in json format.. I am able to print some result but confused in others..

```
  application =         {
        id = 142759389130183;
        name = iphonemini;
    };
    caption = "widevision.co.in";
    "created_time" = "2011-06-14T07:56:38+0000";
    from =         {
        id = 100001507678574;
        name = "Widevision Dev";
    };
    icon = "http://www.facebook.com/images/icons/hidden.gif";
    id = "100001507678574_173203589406562";
    link = "http://widevision.co.in/";
    message = "Good Afternoon";
    name = "Check It out";
    type = link;
    "updated_time" = "2011-06-14T07:56:38+0000";
},
```

I can print this icon, id , link by this code

```
FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphGet:@"me/feed" withGetVars:nil];


    NSLog(@"method called");
    //parse our json
    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *facebook_response = [parser    objectWithString:fb_graph_response.htmlResponse error:nil];    

    [parser release];

    //NSString *feed;
    //  NSString *feed2;
    NSMutableArray *feed =(NSMutableArray *) [facebook_response objectForKey:@"data"];

    //  NSMutableArray *feed1=(NSMutableArray *) [feed valueForKey:@"type"];


    NSLog(@"Feed %@" ,feed );

    NSLog(@"Message is %@ ",[feed valueForKey:@"icon"]);

    NSLog(@"Name is %@",[feed valueForKey:@"name"]);
```

.. also get this

```
from ={
    id= ;
    name = "";
    }


NSMutableArray *streams = (NSMutableArray *)[feed valueForKey:@"from"];



    // loop over all the stream objects and print their titles
        int index;
        NSMutableDictionary *stream;

        for (index = 0; index < [feed count];index++) {
            stream = (NSMutableDictionary *)[streams objectAtIndex:index];



            NSLog(@"Message is %@:",[stream valueForKey:@"name"]);

        }
```

But how can I parse this `comments  = { }....`

```
{
        application =         {
            id = 136664723060869;
            name = Iphoneapp;
        };
        caption = "bit.ly";
        comments =         {
            count = 2;
            data =             (
                                {
                    "created_time" = "2011-06-14T07:39:45+0000";
                    from =                     {
                        id = 100001507678574;
                        name = "Widevision Dev";
                    };
                    id = "100001507678574_164163733643881_1822049";
                    likes = 1;
                    message = hi;
                },
                                {
                    "created_time" = "2011-06-14T08:17:31+0000";
                    from =                     {
                        id = 100001507678574;
                        name = "Widevision Dev";
                    };
                    id = "100001507678574_164163733643881_1822143";
                    message = hmmm;
                }
            );
        };
```

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I see a clear json object here. I would take example of SBJSON where all the JSON is parsed into NSDictionary object, where `application, caption, comments` are the keys. The object for comment again forms a dictionary with keys; `count, data`. Once you get to the `data` you have an array of the entire data and so this array contains multiple dictionary. Getting each dictionary within the array of data should solve your problem. Best of luck.

Comment: I am having problem in post method...how can I set message and id in comment